# Converting a double Integral from Cartesian to Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

Evaluate the following integral

$$\iint_C x\,dx\,dy$$

on the region $C=\left\{ (x,y) : x \in \left[ 0, \sqrt{4 - y^2} \right] \wedge y \in [1,2]\right\}$.

I know $C$ is bounded by the line $y = 1$ and the upper portion of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 4$, but I don't know how to convert to cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_1^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}x \,dx\,dy$?

Comment: yes, sorry, I don't know how to insert these mathematical operators

Comment: No problem, I will edit it in.  Can you integrate $\int_0^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}x\,dx$?

Comment: Wait, where do you see cylindrical coordinates in this problem?  The integral is over a plane region; cylindrical coordinates are used for integrals over regions in space.

Comment: I have done some $\LaTeX$-ing for you. If you want the limits to appear next to $\int$, input \int\limits_0^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}. The double dollar signs are already provided.

Comment: Well I see cylindricals as an easier way to do it, since if you do by cartesian coordinates you will have to convert to trigonometric coordinates, that by the way I did

Comment: Oh, I think I understand your usage.  I more often hear *polar* coordinates for what you're describing rather than *cylindrical.*  But if you can't easily express the region in polar, just try the iterated integral in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to know how it would be like in polar coordinates.

Comment: After reading through the comment section, I believe the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would be of use to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find the intersection of the two curves.  In polar coordinates, the circle has equation $r=2$ and the line $y=1$ has equation
$$
    r \sin\theta = 1 \implies r = \frac{1}{\sin\theta} = \csc\theta
$$
So the intersection occurs when
$$
    2 = \csc\theta \implies \sin\theta = \frac{1}{2}
$$
$\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$ or $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{3}$.
Only $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$ is in the first quadrant.
The other limit for $\theta$ is when $x=0$, or $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

For each $\theta$ in $\left[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, the ray at angle $\theta$ enters the region when $r=\csc\theta$ and exits when $r=2$.  Therefore
$$
    \iint_C x\,dA = \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2}\int_{\csc\theta}^2 (r\cos\theta)(r\,dr\,d\theta) = \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2}\int_{\csc\theta}^2 r^2 \cos\theta\,dr\,d\theta
$$

Comment: One question... why the bounds for theta are π/6 and 2π/3?
Shouldn't it be 0 to π/6?
The figure I draw was the first quadrant of a circle, which was crossed by the line y = 1

Comment: Oh, I forgot the part that $0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{4-x^2}$.  I'll correct.